# Using mod rewrite to change URL with username variable

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

How do I change the following client-side URL

```
domain.com/profile/jung
domain.com/jung (preferable)
```

to a server-side URL of

```
domain.com/profile.php?user_id=100
```

with the username in a php variable?

I know I need to edit my htaccess file with a RewriteCond and RewriteRule but it's still not clear to me...

How does Twitter manage their userpage URLs?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this rule:

```
RewriteRule ^profile/([^/]+)$ profile.php?user_name=$1
```

This will rewrite requests of `/profile/`*`foobar`* to `/profile.php?user_name=`*`foobar`*. Note that you just can rewrite the user name. You script will then have to look up the user ID if necessary.

Comment: Thanks, that worked!  Is there any easy way to remove profile/ from the url?  so that domain.com/jung would work as well?

Alternatively, if I renamed profile.php to p.php, and changed the rewriterule to ^p/, would that affect all pages that started with the letter p?

Comment: Yes it could be removed. But you should ask yourself, if that’s necessary/useful. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/780311/foo-com-alice-vs-foo-com-users-alice

Comment: Excellent, thanks for that!  Just what I was looking for.  Also some things I hadn't even thought about.

Answer (score 1):

Checkout the [RewriteMap](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritemap) function.