# How do I get a username from the URL? myurl.com/username

Tags: php, url, get

On alot of websites, they have it like `myurl.com/username`

How would I go about making this for myself so I don't have to do `myurl.com/user.php?id=123` e.t.c.?

Comment: You need to setup the module URL rewriter for IIS or Apache. That will translate myurl.com/username to myurl.com/user.php?uname=username

Comment: @Ben Shepard - WOW! You've asked **LOADS** of questions, but not accepted any answers... That's really bad...

Comment: see [mod rewrite](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/904075/using-mod-rewrite-to-change-url-with-username-variable)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use an .htacces file

When the file looks like this:

```
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/([\(\)\|a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/?$   /index.php?ext=$1&cat=$2&name=$3&sub1=$4 [L]
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/([\(\)\|a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/?$     /index.php?ext=$1&cat=$2&name=$3 [L]
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/?$    /index.php?ext=$1&cat=$2 [L]
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/?$     /index.php?ext=$1 [L]
```

If youre url is now `myurl.com/username`, you can get the username then by:

```
$username = $_GET['ext'];
```

you can rename the get variables to fit your need in the htacces file.