# url rewriting using .htaccess in php

Tags: php, .htaccess, url, seo, rewriting

I want to change my vendor profile daynamic URL

Right now i have this type of URL that generated from back-end when i add new vendor. http://www.greatyogaplace.com/yoga-school-profile.php?id=20&category=92

but i want to like http://www.greatyogaplace.com/yoga-school-profile/vendorename

If anyone know plzz. help me.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/904075/using-mod-rewrite-to-change-url-with-username-variable

Comment: There are probably give or take 500 other questions almost identical to this - Start from them and then if you can't get it to work show us your code that you are using and what you need it to do and we can help you from there.

Answer (score 2):

Well, Here you need to have vendorname in the URL:

```
RewriteRule ^yoga-school-profile/(.*) yoga-school-profile.php?vendorname=$1
```

currently only id and category id is in the URL, so you need to update yoga-school-profile.php in order to achieve desired functionality

Comment: hello sir thank u for answered. i don't know about ph code. so plzz can u modify my code directly in yoga-school-profile page. plzz access full code from here http://greatyogaplace.com/for-check.html & send me revert on info.anurawat@gmail.com