# Custom url page

Tags: php, html, get

I would like to understand the implementation of custom url like GitHub or Facebook.

For example `https://github.com/YourName` or `https://www.facebook.com/YourName` redirect to your personal web page.
I would understand if it was more like `https://github.com/profil?name=YourName` or `https://www.facebook.com/profil?name=YourName`.

But now I'm confused. How to implement this system?

Comment: `Url rewrite` is a search term

Comment: example here [using-mod-rewrite-to-change-url-with-username-variable](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/904075/using-mod-rewrite-to-change-url-with-username-variable)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You get the web server to preform a URL rewrite to point any requested URLs that don't match an existing file or folder to a php file.

For Apache it would look something like this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ app.php [QSA,L]
```

Then in app.php you can use $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'] to get the URL the user requested.