# Shorten URL using htaccess file

Tags: .htaccess, url-shortener

I have the url

`www.example.com/profile?username=abc`

and i want to rewrite it as

`www.example.com/abc`

How can I achieve this using htaccess?

Comment: possible duplicate of [foo.com/alice vs. foo.com/users/alice](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/780311/foo-com-alice-vs-foo-com-users-alice)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

RewriteCond to avoid infinite redirection

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/profile
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /profile?username=$1
```

Comment: ./\. Working perfectly!!

Comment: if you want only `abc` use `RewriteRule ^abc$ /profile?username=abc`

Comment: i want to implement it the way facebook does

Comment: You can't different input of user name from any page name in htaccess. Only if all pages are static. Undestanding of contents must be made in code